# Set value of a field without calling set method - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, getter-setter

I've been using Kotlin to develop some apps in Android and what i want to do currently is to set a field value inside the defining class without calling the setter method.

Here is the code inside my class:

```
var projectList: List<Project>? = null
    set(value) {
        saveProjects(value as ArrayList<Project>)
        field = value
    }

//GO to the database and retrieve list of projects
fun loadProjects(callback: Project.OnProjectsLoadedListener) {
   database.projectDao().getAll().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(

                    { success ->
                        callback.onProjectsLoaded(success)
                    //Here i don't want to save the projects, because i've loaded them from the database
                        this.projectList = success
                    },
                    { error -> GenericErrorHandler.handleError(error,callback.retrieveContext())}

                    )
}
```

Does anybody know a way to do this without calling the `set(value)` method?

Comment: Use a constructor?

Comment: @Zoe Not sure how that is applicable here. Care to explain?

Comment: If you want to set a value without using  set method or calling the variable directly (more or less the same as using getters and setters) the only option is doign it when the object is created. hence a constructor

Comment: But loadProject() method is called on a previously constructed object. This code is all in the same class. I just want to set value to a field without calling the setter. In java it would just be `this.projectList = X` and for setter it would be `setProjectList(X)` but here i don't know how to call the field without triggering `set(value)` method.

Comment: If all the code is in Kotlin, you just use `this.projectList = x` too. If you call Kotlin from Java you have to use getters and setters, but from internally in Kotlin the compiler calls the getters and setters automatically. Unless that's what you're trying to avoid, in which case I just recommend you rename the custom getters and setters so nothing special happens when it's set

Comment: @Zoe In other words there is no way to set a value to the field in Kotlin without calling it's setter method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only gain access to the field directly from the setter. Inside a setter, the field can be accessed through the invisible `field` variable.

There are perhaps some other ways around your requirements though. Here are 2 examples. You wouldn't have to follow them exactly, but could instead also combine them to make whatever solution you want.

**You could use another shell property to act as the setter for your actual property:**

```
class Example1 {
  var fieldProperty: Int = 0

  var setterPropertyForField: Int
    get() = fieldProperty
    set(value) { 
      fieldProperty = value 
    }
}
```

**You could use setters as you actually would in Java with a JVM field and a set method. The `@JvmField` is probably not necessary.**

```
class Example2 {
  @JvmField var fieldProperty: Int = 0

  fun setField(value: Int) {
    fieldProperty = value
  }
}
```

You could probably access the field and change it through reflection, but I don't recommend that approach. That would likely only lead to problems.

Comment: It would be cool if JVMField annotation worked so that it lets you access the field itself rather than setter method. I searched for that sort of answer but there is no way, so thank you for giving me examples of how it should be done! :)